# JSON output with Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have been experimenting with the groovy Jsonbuilder as you can see below trying to look at different ways to build JSON objects and arrays.  After things started to make sense, I tried expanding to what is shown below.  The question I have is, why does "content" show up in the json pretty string output?  I actually have another json object displaying this.class information in json string outputs.

Any ideas?  I'm new to this, so it could definitely be an obvious one.

```
def tt = ["test", "test1"]
def jjj = "jason"
def js3 = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def js2 = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(tt);
js3 hello: "$jjj", "$jjj": tt
def js4 = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def result = js4([sdn: js3, openflow: js2, type: 3])
println js4.toPrettyString();
```

outputs:

```
{
    "sdn": {
        "content": {
            "hello": "jason",
            "jason": [
                "test",
                "test1"
            ]
        }
    },
    "openflow": {
        "content": [
            "test",
            "test1"
        ]
    },
    "type": 3
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem can be restated as...

why does this:

```
import groovy.json.*

def js3 = new JsonBuilder(["test", "test1"])
def js4 = new JsonBuilder(js3)
println js4.toString()
```

print:

```
{"content":["test","test1"]}
```

and this:

```
import groovy.json.*

def js3 = new JsonBuilder(["test", "test1"])
def js4 = new JsonBuilder(js3.content)
println js4.toString()
```

prints this (?) :

```
["test","test1"]
```

The short answer is that JsonBuilder has a member named `content`, which represents the payload. When one JsonBuilder absorbs another, we want to replace the payload, and not nest it. This line is the way to replace the payload:

def js4 = new JsonBuilder(js3.content)

Ultimately, this stems from the fact that `JsonBuilder.toString()` ([code here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.java)) calls `JsonOutput.toJson(object)` ([code here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonOutput.java)).

An exercise for the reader is to experiment with:

```
class MyBuilder {
    def content
}

def myB = new MyBuilder(content: ["test", "test1"])
println JsonOutput.toJson(myB)
println JsonOutput.toJson(myB.content)
```

Comment: It's a very good explanation. You may want to update the "code  here" links now that Groovy sources have moved.