# JSON pretty print customization

Tags: java, json, groovy, formatting

I'm writing a tool to modify huge json file in groovy. I read this file, add new entry and save, but I'would like to avoid changes in places I didn't touch.

I'm using `new JsonBuilder( o ).toPrettyString()` to get pretty formatted json output, but this function gives me result like this:

```
{
    "key": "Foo",
    "items": [
        {
            "Bar1": 1
        },
        {
            "Bar2": 2
        }
    ]   
}
```

when I need to get this:

```
{
    "key": "Foo",
    "items": 
    [
        {
            "Bar1": 1
        },
        {
            "Bar2": 2
        }
    ]   
}
```

There should be newline before `[`.

It's important to me, because in other way I cannot find in GIT history, what I really changed.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Is that what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül no, there are javascript solutions

Comment: check this maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018063/json-output-with-groovy

Answer (score 0):

The `JsonBuilder` method `toPrettyString()` delegates directly to `JsonOutput.prettyPrint()` as follows:

```
public String toPrettyString() {
    return JsonOutput.prettyPrint(toString());
}
```

The latter method is not really customizable at all. However, the source is freely available from any Maven central repository or mirror. I would suggest finding the source and creating your own variant of the method that behaves the way you would like it to. The source for `JsonOutput.prettyPrint()` is only about 65 lines long and shouldn't be that hard to change.